# IllegalArgumentValueException calling addSiteAccount1

Tags: yodlee

I am not having much success getting the `addSiteAccount1` API to work. I am using .NET, but I don't believe that has anything to do with my issue. Seems like I am missing something in the request, however I have read the documentation and other posts, but can't figure out what might be missing.

Here is my request (captured from Fiddler):

```
cobSessionToken <<REMOVED>>
userSessionToken    <<REMOVED>>
siteId  2852
credentialFields[1].valueMask   LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].value   <<REMOVED>>
credentialFields[1].size    20
credentialFields[1].name    PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].maxLength   20
credentialFields[1].isOptionalMFA   False
credentialFields[1].isOptional  False
credentialFields[1].isMFA   False
credentialFields[1].isEscaped   False
credentialFields[1].isEditable  True
credentialFields[1].helpText    5372
credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName  IF_PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].fieldInfoType   com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
credentialFields[1].displayName Passcode
credentialFields[0].valueMask   LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier LOGIN
credentialFields[0].value   <<REMOVED>>
credentialFields[0].size    20
credentialFields[0].name    LOGIN
credentialFields[0].maxLength   40
credentialFields[0].isOptionalMFA   False
credentialFields[0].isOptional  False
credentialFields[0].isMFA   False
credentialFields[0].isEscaped   False
credentialFields[0].isEditable  True
credentialFields[0].helpText    5371
credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName  IF_LOGIN
credentialFields[0].fieldInfoType   com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
credentialFields[0].displayName Online ID
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Unknown
yodlee-ref-id: q1464831683738d12W27T
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6E8CF7DA66E80B567118AF1956589519; Path=/services; Secure
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 01:41:22 GMT
Server: Unknown
  {"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException","referenceCode":"_54f9c9b6-60f9-49d9-8aa6-43542d7ec598","message":"Null argument specified"}
```

I have also tried the suggested answer (removing `fieldInfoType` and adding `enclosedType`):

```
cobSessionToken <<REMOVED>>
userSessionToken    <<REMOVED>>
siteId  2852
credentialFields.enclosedType   com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
credentialFields[0].displayName Online ID
credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName  IF_LOGIN
credentialFields[0].helpText    5371
credentialFields[0].maxLength   40
credentialFields[0].name    LOGIN
credentialFields[0].size    20
credentialFields[0].value   <<REMOVED>>
credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier LOGIN
credentialFields[0].valueMask   LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[0].isEditable  True
credentialFields[0].isOptional  False
credentialFields[0].isEscaped   False
credentialFields[0].isOptionalMFA   False
credentialFields[0].isMFA   False
credentialFields[1].displayName Passcode
credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName  IF_PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].helpText    5372
credentialFields[1].maxLength   20
credentialFields[1].name    PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].size    20
credentialFields[1].value   <<REMOVED>>
credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].valueMask   LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[1].isEditable  True
credentialFields[1].isOptional  False
credentialFields[1].isEscaped   False
credentialFields[1].isOptionalMFA   False
credentialFields[1].isMFA   False
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Unknown
yodlee-ref-id: q1465437863468f12C27S
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3600322EF154E726209C217844FF935E; Path=/services; Secure
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2016 02:04:22 GMT
Server: Unknown

{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.IncompleteArgumentException","referenceCode":"_418a82c7-90b9-4a1f-8aad-87ba16cfbb67","message":"Incomplete argument: FieldInfoSingle: {FieldInfo: name=\"null\" displayName=\"null\" editable=false optional=false helpText=\"null\" valuePattern=\"null\" } defaultValue=\"null\" value=\"null\" validValues=[null] displayValidValues=[null] valueIdentifier=\"null\" valueMask=\"null\" fieldType=\"null\" validationRules=[null] size=null maxlength=null userProfileMappingExpression=null fieldErrorCode=null fieldErrorMessage=null "}
```

I can tell what the null argument might be...

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your login form

```
credentialFields.enclosedType com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
```

instead of

```
credentialFields[1].fieldInfoType com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle

credentialFields[0].fieldInfoType com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I get `IncompleteArgumentException`, see update above

Comment: Hi Jay , I've built the login form for  this using Postman(Chrome Application) : Requesting you to download the collection from the following link : https://www.getpostman.com/collections/e2bb6b259add1dfbfcdd